# segmentaion fault in childprocess gem-Ruby 1.9.3p545

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, rubygems

Getting an error while launching the browser through ruby code in irb

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
 $profile = Selenium::WebDriver::firefox::Profile.new      
 $profile.native_events = true
 $browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => $profile
```

**StackTrace:**

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.5.6/lib/childprocess/windows/lib.rb:311: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0049 p:---- s:0196 b:0196 l:000195 d:000195 CFUNC  :get_osfhandle
c:0048 p:0122 s:0192 b:0192 l:000191 d:000191 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.5.6/lib/childprocess/windows/lib.rb:311
c:0047 p:0066 s:0186 b:0185 l:000184 d:000184 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.5.6/lib/childprocess/windows/lib.rb:270
c:0046 p:0213 s:0181 b:0181 l:000180 d:000180 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.5.6/lib/childprocess.rb:153
c:0045 p:0054 s:0176 b:0176 l:000175 d:000175 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:46
c:0044 p:0051 s:0172 b:0172 l:000171 d:000171 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:31
c:0043 p:0011 s:0168 b:0168 l:000167 d:000167 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:17
c:0042 p:0017 s:0164 b:0164 l:00028c d:00028c METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:32
c:0041 p:0175 s:0161 b:0161 l:000160 d:000160 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:24
c:0040 p:---- s:0151 b:0151 l:000150 d:000150 FINISH
c:0039 p:---- s:0149 b:0149 l:000148 d:000148 CFUNC  :new
c:0038 p:0212 s:0145 b:0145 l:000144 d:000144 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31
c:0037 p:0021 s:0138 b:0138 l:000137 d:000137 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67
c:0036 p:0126 s:0134 b:0134 l:000133 d:000133 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46
c:0035 p:---- s:0129 b:0129 l:000128 d:000128 FINISH
c:0034 p:---- s:0127 b:0127 l:000126 d:000126 CFUNC  :new
c:0033 p:1337 s:0122 b:0122 l:000d38 d:000121 BLOCK  C:/jenkins_slave_jd1-rhel5-9/workspace/Device_Addition_and_Collection_Status_Sanity_on_CI_Build/GUI-Automation/lib/common/spec_
c:0032 p:---- s:0113 b:0113 l:000112 d:000112 FINISH
c:0031 p:---- s:0111 b:0111 l:000110 d:000110 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0030 p:0021 s:0107 b:0107 l:000106 d:000106 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:357
c:0029 p:0014 s:0103 b:0103 l:000094 d:000102 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:517
c:0028 p:---- s:0100 b:0100 l:000099 d:000099 FINISH
c:0027 p:---- s:0098 b:0098 l:000097 d:000097 CFUNC  :each
c:0026 p:0023 s:0095 b:0095 l:000094 d:000094 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:516
c:0025 p:0056 s:0089 b:0089 l:000088 d:000088 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:469
c:0024 p:0022 s:0083 b:0083 l:000068 d:000082 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:462
c:0023 p:0015 s:0081 b:0081 l:000073 d:000080 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:141
c:0022 p:---- s:0079 b:0079 l:000078 d:000078 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0020 p:0017 s:0074 b:0074 l:000073 d:000073 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:137
c:0019 p:0040 s:0069 b:0069 l:000068 d:000068 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:461
c:0018 p:0138 s:0065 b:0065 l:000064 d:000064 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:511
c:0017 p:0014 s:0057 b:0057 l:000035 d:000056 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110
c:0016 p:---- s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0052 b:0052 l:000051 d:000051 CFUNC  :map
c:0014 p:0011 s:0049 b:0049 l:000035 d:000048 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110
c:0013 p:0062 s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526
c:0012 p:0011 s:0043 b:0043 l:000035 d:000042 BLOCK  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109
c:0011 p:0022 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62
c:0010 p:0030 s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108
c:0009 p:0034 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86
c:0008 p:0120 s:0027 b:0027 l:000026 d:000026 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70
c:0007 p:0032 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38
c:0006 p:0031 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4
c:0005 p:---- s:0014 b:0014 l:000013 d:000013 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0167 s:0008 b:0008 l:000404 d:00234c EVAL   C:/Ruby193/bin/rspec:23
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000404 d:000404 TOP
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and was able to fix it by reverting to ffi 1.9.8 instead of 1.9.9
See https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/440